# Yii2 facebook & google login

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, yii2

I want to implement social logins in Yii 2 application.

I checked the follwoing [repo](http://nodge.ru/yii-eauth/demo2/)

but when I require it in my composer.json file it throws me the following error

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for nodge/yii2-eauth dev-master -> satisfiable by nodge/yii2-eauth[dev-master].
- nodge/yii2-eauth dev-master requires yiisoft/yii2 dev-master@dev -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.
```

I researched about alternative libraries, but no luck. Any other yii2 extensions with which I can make a user login using facebook ?

Comment: Take a look at the AuthClient extension for Yii 2: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-authclient-index.html

Comment: https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user

Answer (score 1):

Run following composer command for the correct library...
It worked for me...

```
composer require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-authclient "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using Yii 1.x and I implemented a login system using the plugin YUM (Yii User Management).
I had a lot of trouble fixing bugs and adding the Facebook login functionality.
At the end, I decided to write my own code for the login system.

In my opinion, it's better to rely on a third-party plugin. You won't have the hassle of updating your own code every time Facebook (or Twitter etc.) changes their API. That's one of the benefits of open source softwares.

I would highly recommend HybridAuth: http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/

It has plugins for every PHP frameworks:
http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/plugins.html